# How to check how many keys stored in Aerospike?

Tags: cache, aerospike

I am new to Aerospike and exploring AQL and ASADM.

I Executed command "show sets" and got response -

```
aql> show sets
+------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| disable-eviction | ns          | objects | stop-writes-count | set           | memory_data_bytes | device_data_bytes | truncate_lut | tombstones |
+------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
| "false"          | "tvpreprod" | "35249" | "0"               | "data"        | "1684642852"      | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvpreprod" | "12229" | "0"               | "epg"         | "3035957260"      | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvpreprod" | "6009"  | "0"               | "account"     | "6288324"         | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvpreprod" | "24821" | "0"               | "epg_account" | "59593681"        | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvstage"   | "2956"  | "0"               | "data"        | "66573412"        | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvstage"   | "1873"  | "0"               | "account"     | "1984140"         | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvstage"   | "18060" | "0"               | "epg_account" | "30209254"        | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
| "false"          | "tvstage"   | "5197"  | "0"               | "epg"         | "1792880530"      | "0"               | "0"          | "0"        |
+------------------+-------------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+
[xx.xx.xx.xx:3000] 8 rows in set (0.781 secs)
```

But on executing : select * from tvstage.data, I got result -

```
138 rows in set (3.796 secs)
```

I am not able to understand why there is difference in count?

**Show sets** gives 2956 records, but **Select** shows only 138 records.

All the keys pushed are having different TTLs and expiry is set to not more than 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the records have expired and nsup has not deleted them? The set stat would show those but you wouldn't be able to retrieve those records. You can check from the logs when nsup ran last (grep for nsup in the logs).

Ok, answer in [your other question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/316052/aerospike-memory-usage-increasing-constantly-with-time/316256#316256). You should configure `nsup-period xx` and not use `allow-ttl-without-nsup true` otherwise your expired records will never be deleted.